# What happened to Rhino? Is it still under active development?

Tags: java, rhino, scripting-language

The last release was in 2008-03-06. What happened to it? Is it still under active development? Are there any replacements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly modified version of Rhino (1.6r2) is [part of Java 6](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/04/26/mustang-meets-rhino-java-se-6-scripting.html) and on top of that from what I've tested Rhino is very much feature complete so there really isn't anything left to develop onwards, apparently it's also quite bug-free also.

I'd say Rhino is one of those rare libraries which are actually done.

Answer (score 3):

According to a post last week at http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/topics

```
On Mar 9, 11:45 am, Rhino user <anupama.jo...@gmail.com> wrote:

> Does  anybody has any tentative dates for 1.7R2 release?

I need to look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=482203
but other than that it is ready to go.
```

Answer (score 1):

This question might better be asked at the relevant newsgroup: mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.
Or by mail to one of the responsible developers as [mentioned at the Mozilla site](http://www.mozilla.org/owners.html).

However, if you found out please post the answer here. I'm interested too.